# How to format input value to DD/MM/YYYY using Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, date, input, vuejs2

I've an input where user can enter date and while typing I'd like to format it's value to `DD/MM/YYYY`. So when input value matches the required format I'd like to restrict the user from being typing.

```
<template>
  <input v-model="dob" @input="handleInput">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dob: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput(e) {
      let value = e.target.value;
      this.dob = this.$options.filters.formatTo(value, "date");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

this is the filter I tried,

```
Vue.filter('formatTo', function(value, format) {
  const formats = {
    date: {
      blocks: [2, 2, 4],
      delimeter: '/'
    }
  };

  if (!value || !(format in formats)) return;

  const { blocks, delimeter } = formats[format];
  const numberOfBlocks = blocks.length - 1;
  const maxLength = numberOfBlocks + blocks.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  let index = -1;

  value = value.toString().split('');

  blocks.map(block => {
    index += block + 1; // here +1 is for delimeter
    value.splice(index, 0, delimeter);
  });

  // remove excess values
  value.length = value.length > maxLength ? maxLength : value.length;

  return value.join('').trim();
});
```

Comment: What did you try...?

Comment: @sajahan updated

Comment: Checkout [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @Ace I would like to format it while typing like, automatically adding `/` after typing day and adding second `/` after typing month

Comment: Modifying user input while they are typing makes for a horrible user experience and requires you to write lots of code for zero useful functionality. Just let the user enter the date and don't pester them with stuff you think is cool and they will likely find annoying.

Comment: @Ace—what specific functionality does moment.js have for masking or editing user input as they type?

Comment: @RobG I had misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am creating a mask based on the length of the string. When the length hits 2, the first `/` is applied, when it hits 4, the second `/` is applied. Then you'll want to limit the input to 8 characters.

```js
const createMask = string => {
  const length = string.length;
  const regex = /(\d{0,2})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,4})/;
   if(length < 2){
     return string;
   }
   if(length <= 3){
     return string.replace(regex, "$1\/$2");
   }
    return string.replace(regex,"$1\/$2\/$3");
}

console.log(createMask('12241990'))
```

Comment: thanks, I tried this solution as well, but when hit backspace after first slash or second slash the it is not working as expected. Ex: after `12/` or `12/05/`

Comment: Right. Might have to do some sort of trick with hiding the real input and showing the masked one. Or maybe just try a [masking library](https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/#article-header-id-1)

Comment: And if the user types "2/7/2019" what happens? Most users watch the keyboard as they type, particularly on mobile devices, they might be surprised at what confronts them when they look back at the input. ;-)

Comment: Sure, but that isn't necessarily what people type. A UI should be helpful and friendly, not prescriptive and annoying.

Comment: @Naresh Do you have anything against the native date input?